# How can I make a Keynote file non-editable?

Tags: ipad, keynote, iwork

I have a PowerPoint presentation that I am converting to Keynote to distribute to students; however, I do not want other users to be able to edit the presentation.

Is there a way to make a Keynote file read-only, non-editable?

I don’t want to convert it to PDF files as I will lose the animations, or to convert it to a video file as the students would lose the ability to read the presentation at their own pace.

Answer (score 2):

To make a Keynote presentation non-editable, you can export the slides as images and replace all the original slides with the images.

Comment: This actually is decent workaround. Nothing is preventing someone from editing the pictures or making a second presentation and substituting an entire slide - but it makes it harder to go in and casually replace a few words. It does ruin any scaling and transitions that occur within a page - so if you use builds or magic moves, this isn't a good option.

Comment: Depending on the number of slides this is quite a loot of work. Exporting them as/Printing them into a PDF and just using this for the presentation is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, you can only use a password to limit file open and presentation stop.

However you can include a keynote presentation in an iBook by using iBooks Author.

You can do that by creating an iBook with a single page and using the Keynote Widget for including the presentation on your iBook.

However I never tried to publish the book, and I don't know exactly how it works. [Here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/content-providers/book-faq.html) you can find more information.

Answer (score 0):

Keynote hasn't programmed in the facility to mark a file as locked for editing but open for reading. On OS X, if you're an administrator of the machines you could use the normal file read and write permissions. It can [set a password on a keynote file](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6016),  but people that can open the file can edit it.

If you don't have that control over all of the devices, you might not be able to accomplish this by using the native keynote format. Also, it's not even clear you can set a password from iOS and must use the OS X version of the app to even set a password in the first place.